# Firestore "listen" to latest N updates and paginate the rest

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have hundreds of documents in my Firestore, each document can go upto 1MB in size, this is the format:

```
{
  updatedAt: serverTimeStamp
  userIds: [1,2,3] //who should receive the updates 
  ...rest of the data
}
```

I want to update the UI real-time on any new document added or existing is modified which matches the query. And I want to be able paginate for the rest.

Solution: Listen to 1 document and order by `updatedAt` so that latest updates always reach the UI.

Here's the query I wrote:

```
query(
    collection(
      firestoreInstance,
     "myCollection"
    ),
     where("userIds", "array-contains", currentUserId)
    orderBy("updatedAt","desc"),
    limit(1)
  );
```

But the problem is, its only "subscribing" to 1 document, any other documents added or updates its not getting that change.

for example if I add a new document

```
{
  updatedAt: now()
  userIds: [currentUserId] 
  ...rest of the data
}
```

I want the UI to get this newly added document, or if update any existing document containing `currentUserId` i want the UI to get the updates, but my query is not working as expected,It works as expected if I remove the `limit`, but i want to limit the realtime update because subscribing to all documents belonging to a user is both expensive and slow.

Am I missing something in my query? or thats how firestore works? it subscribes to the exact documents than the query(dynamic subscription)?

I cant listen to all document as it could be huge in number and take forever to load the UI.

Comment: What is your definition of "efficient" here that would allow you to mark an answer as accepted? To be honest, there is not going to be anything perfectly efficient because what you're describing is not really an expected use case for Firestore. Realtime updates and pagination simply do not mix in the SDK.

Comment: anything more efficient or the most efficient solution.
consider a messaging app how to handle 100s of chats or groups?

Comment: @DougStevenson also does that mean my assumption is correct? client only subscribe to the latest doc at that point, it wont dynamically change the document its subscribed to?

Comment: If you have a different question than the one here, I suggest posting it separately so it can have its own accepted answer.

Comment: its the same question, thats my first approach in fact. i want to know if i'm missing something or thats how firestore is, if its the later how should this be achieved with firestore

Comment: Your question as written is "What is the efficient way to listen to realtime updates and paginate the rest?" Would you like the edit the post to change that to your new question about your assumptions?

Comment: Why can't you listen for all documents in the collection rather than latest N updates, using [Listen to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) like what I have done  in this [snippet](https://codefile.io/f/2sZO4iKudA)

Comment: Now you have multiple questions in a single post, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently adding limit to firestore snapshot query "fixes" the documents the query listens to,I dint find any documentation to support this claim apart from my own experience.
so the solution i followed is to subscribe to last 1 hour updates, with this i wont have to receive so many documents(then paying egress and read price) on initial load, and paginate the rest as and when required, here's the sample logic

1. subscribe to last 1 hour updates

```
const q = query(
    collection(
      firestoreInstance,
     "myCollection"
    ),
     where("userIds", "array-contains", currentUserId),
     where("updatedAt",">=",last1HourOldDate)
    orderBy("updatedAt","desc"),
  );
onSnapshot(q,handler,errorHandler)
```

2. paginate the rest as and when user scrolls to the bottom of the page

```
const q = query(
    collection(
      firestoreInstance,
     "myCollection"
    ),
     where("userIds", "array-contains", currentUserId),
     where("updatedAt","<",last1HourOldDate)
    orderBy("updatedAt","desc"),
    limit(20),
  );
const docs = await getDocs(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is, its only "subscribing" to 1 document, any other documents added or updates its not getting that change.

That's the way it works.  A listener on a query will only deliver you updates on the changes to the documents that are added, updated, or deleted in the results of the query, even as its results change over time.  You will know nothing about any other document in the collection.

The only way to get updates on any document in the collection is to query for all the documents and listen to the results.

Comment: I tried few things & added more details to my query, it seems if I remove limit, query works as expected, is there a way to achieve the requirement with limit?

Comment: No, as I said in my answer, that's not the way it works. If the results of the query contain 1 document, then you will receive updates about 1 document.

Comment: i hope we mean the same, lets say i subscribed with limit 1, and now query matches only 1 document, i get that 1 document, but if i add 1 more document that matches query, i wont get it, if i dint add the limit in the 1st place i would have got new additions.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're saying. I think it would be easier if you just tried to do the thing you're asking about and observe for yourself how it works.